# Codeigniter use show_error method to load your own error template file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the Codeigniter's `show_error` method from `/system/core/exceptions.php`

```
public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500)
    {
        $templates_path = config_item('error_views_path');
        if (empty($templates_path))
        {
            $templates_path = VIEWPATH.'errors'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }

        if (is_cli())
        {
            $message = "\t".(is_array($message) ? implode("\n\t", $message) : $message);
            $template = 'cli'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$template;
        }
        else
        {
            set_status_header($status_code);
            $message = '<p>'.(is_array($message) ? implode('</p><p>', $message) : $message).'</p>';
            $template = 'html'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$template;
        }

        if (ob_get_level() > $this->ob_level + 1)
        {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
        ob_start();
        include($templates_path.$template.'.php');
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $buffer;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to call this function from my controller, now if I was to do so then I can pass a `$heading`, `$message`, `$template` and `$status_code`.

Now i'm trying to make my own 401 HTTP Unauthorised error page so i've created a view file inside `/application/views/errors/html/error_401.php` now in my controller I'm trying to do this:

```
show_error('401 Unauthorised', 'You are not authorised to access this page.', 'error_401', 401);
```

So i'm passing my heading and message which is for the view file itself that I created `error_401.php`. I've also told the function that the template I want to load is `error_401`.

However, It still persists on loading `error_general` rather than `error_401`. Is there a reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_404

Comment: Is it possible to do without playing around like that? I mean for a website it's a great fix. But i'm trying to use my error_401 in a library and well, the fewer dependencies and alterations the better.

Comment: Hmm not sure how to do it without the routes.. sorry buddy

Comment: I just don't understand why the exceptions show_error allows you to pass a template but ignores it...

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would to simply re-create the method for your library.

```
public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $code = 404)
  {
    $template_path = APPPATH.'views/library_name/errors';
    if ($this->config->item('error_view_path', 'library_name'))
    {
      $template_path = $this->config->item('error_view_path', 'library_name');
    }
    if (is_cli())
        {
            $message = "\t".(is_array($message) ? implode("\n\t", $message) : $message);
            $template = 'cli'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$template;
        }
        else
        {
            set_status_header($code);
            $message = '<p>'.(is_array($message) ? implode('</p><p>', $message) : $message).'</p>';
            $template = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$template;
        }

        ob_start();
        include($template_path.$template.'.php');
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $buffer;
    exit();
  }
```

Basically taken from `/system/core/Exceptions.php`, but does the trick easily.

Alternatively http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_404 as mentioned by @Patrick.